# Errors appear while indexing on Red Hat Linux 11.0.2 WEX CA

Tags: linux, analytics, redhat, watson

To use the machine learning annotator in WEX, recently I have set up the Linux Red Hat 7.2.

Everything was fine during creating collection and configuring the M/L annotator.

After crawling some documents, when I try to restart whole indexing session and then errors appear.

Only the 'Parse and Index' session occurs errors.

Some doc said that the error message 'Bluemax engine initialization failed!' might means the problem associated with environmental variables.

So I checked the environmental variables, It turns out to be fine It seems.

Is there anyone who knows about this problem?

Errors are as following...

```
*FFQO0277E An exception was caught with the detail 'com.ibm.es.oze.indexservice.internal.IndexerTask$TokenizerInitializationException: FFQEI0006E' and a stack trace of 'com.ibm.es.oze.indexservice.internal.IndexerTask$TokenizerInitializationException: FFQEI0006E at com.ibm.es.oze.indexservice.internal.IndexerTask$DocumentCollector.afterProcessing(IndexerTask.java:270) at com.ibm.es.oze.indexservice.internal.IndexerTask.processDocument(IndexerTask.java:1004) at com.ibm.es.oze.indexservice.internal.IndexerTask.run(IndexerTask.java:662) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1153) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:785) '.
Details FFQEI0006E The index build failed to start.
FFQO0277E An exception was caught with the detail 'com.ibm.es.oze.indexservice.internal.IndexerTask$SevereIndexerTaskException: FFQEI0011E' and a stack trace of 'com.ibm.es.oze.indexservice.internal.IndexerTask$SevereIndexerTaskException: FFQEI0011E at com.ibm.es.oze.indexservice.internal.IndexerTask.run(IndexerTask.java:679) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1153) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:785) Caused by: com.ibm.es.oze.indexservice.internal.IndexerTask$TokenizerInitializationException: FFQEI0006E at com.ibm.es.oze.indexservice.internal.IndexerTask$DocumentCollector.afterProcessing(IndexerTask.java:270) at com.ibm.es.oze.indexservice.internal.IndexerTask.processDocument(IndexerTask.java:1004) at com.ibm.es.oze.indexservice.internal.IndexerTask.run(IndexerTask.java:662) ... 3 more '.
FFQEI0011E An error occurred while the index task indexer-task-1 was processing the documents.
FFQEI0080E The index service is stopped because the UIMA pipeline failed to initialize.
FFQO0277E An exception was caught with the detail 'java.lang.Exception: Bluemax engine initialization failed!' and a stack trace of 'java.lang.Exception: Bluemax engine initialization failed! at com.ibm.nlp.bluemax.SIREAnnotator.init_FAIL(SIREAnnotator.java:175) at com.ibm.nlp.bluemax.SIREAnnotator.initialize(SIREAnnotator.java:289) at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.initializeAnalysisComponent(PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.java:262) at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.initialize(PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.java:169) at org.apache.uima.impl.AnalysisEngineFactory_impl.produceResource(AnalysisEngineFactory_impl.java:94) at org.apache.uima.impl.CompositeResourceFactory_impl.produceResource(CompositeResourceFactory_impl.java:62) at org.apache.uima.UIMAFramework.produceResource(UIMAFramework.java:279) at org.apache.uima.UIMAFramework.produceAnalysisEngine(UIMAFramework.java:407) at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.asb.impl.ASB_impl.setup(ASB_impl.java:256) at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.AggregateAnalysisEngine_impl.initASB(AggregateAnalysisEngine_impl.java:429) at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.AggregateAnalysisEngine_impl.initializeAggregateAnalysisEngine(AggregateAnalysisEngine_impl.java:373) at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.AggregateAnalysisEngine_impl.initialize(AggregateAnalysisEngine_impl.java:186) at org.apache.uima.impl.AnalysisEngineFactory_impl.produceResource(AnalysisEngineFactory_impl.java:94) at org.apache.uima.impl.CompositeResourceFactory_impl.produceResource(CompositeResourceFactory_impl.java:62) at org.apache.uima.UIMAFramework.produceResource(UIMAFramework.java:279) at org.apache.uima.UIMAFramework.produceAnalysisEngine(UIMAFramework.java:407) at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.asb.impl.ASB_impl.setup(ASB_impl.java:256) at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.AggregateAnalysisEngine_impl.initASB(AggregateAnalysisEngine_impl.java:429) at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.AggregateAnalysisEngine_impl.initializeAggregateAnalysisEngine(AggregateAnalysisEngine_impl.java:373) at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.AggregateAnalysisEngine_impl.initialize(AggregateAnalysisEngine_impl.java:186) at org.apache.uima.impl.AnalysisEngineFactory_impl.produceResource(AnalysisEngineFactory_impl.java:94) at org.apache.uima.impl.CompositeResourceFactory_impl.produceResource(CompositeResourceFactory_impl.java:62) at org.apache.uima.UIMAFramework.produceResource(UIMAFramework.java:279) at org.apache.uima.UIMAFramework.produceResource(UIMAFramework.java:331) at org.apache.uima.UIMAFramework.produceAnalysisEngine(UIMAFramework.java:448) at com.ibm.es.nuvo.tokenizer.uima.AbstractCASTokenizer.initUimaTae(AbstractCASTokenizer.java:481) at com.ibm.es.nuvo.tokenizer.uima.AbstractCASTokenizer.configure(AbstractCASTokenizer.java:361) at com.ibm.es.nuvo.tokenizer.uima.CASTokenizer.configure(CASTokenizer.java:208) at com.ibm.es.oze.tokenizer.ExportableCASTokenizer.configure(ExportableCASTokenizer.java:126) at com.ibm.es.oze.tokenizer.OzeCASTokenizer.configure(OzeCASTokenizer.java:92) at com.ibm.es.oze.indexservice.internal.TokenizerFactory$1.configure(TokenizerFactory.java:168) at com.ibm.ilel.tokenizer.service.TokenizerRegistry.create(TokenizerRegistry.java:89) at com.ibm.ilel.tokenizer.service.SingleTokenizerPool.acquire(SingleTokenizerPool.java:242) at com.ibm.ilel.tokenizer.service.AggregateTokenizerPool.acquire(AggregateTokenizerPool.java:107) at com.ibm.ilel.tokenizer.service.AggregateTokenizerPool.acquire(AggregateTokenizerPool.java:65) at com.ibm.ilel.tokenizer.DocumentProcessor.process(DocumentProcessor.java:98) at com.ibm.es.nuvo.tokenizer.XMLDocumentProcessor.tokenizeDocument(XMLDocumentProcessor.java:93) at com.ibm.es.oze.indexservice.internal.dps.embedded.EmbeddedDocumentProcessorDeployer$EmbeddedDocumentProcessor.tokenize(EmbeddedDocumentProcessorDeployer.java:745) at com.ibm.es.oze.indexservice.internal.dps.embedded.EmbeddedDocumentProcessorDeployer$EmbeddedDocumentProcessor.process(EmbeddedDocumentProcessorDeployer.java:666) at com.ibm.es.oze.indexservice.internal.dps.embedded.EmbeddedDocumentProcessorDeployer$EmbeddedDocumentProcessor.process(EmbeddedDocumentProcessorDeployer.java:571) at com.ibm.es.oze.indexservice.internal.dps.socket.SocketDocumentProcessingServer$Worker.processDocument(SocketDocumentProcessingServer.java:784) at com.ibm.es.oze.indexservice.internal.dps.socket.QueuedSocketDocumentProcessingServer$QueueWorker.processDocument(QueuedSocketDocumentProcessingServer.java:106) at com.ibm.es.oze.indexservice.internal.dps.socket.SocketDocumentProcessingServer$Worker.run(SocketDocumentProcessingServer.java:683) '.
FFQO0277E An exception was caught with the detail 'org.apache.uima.resource.ResourceInitializationException' and a stack trace of 'org.apache.uima.resource.ResourceInitializationException at com.ibm.nlp.bluemax.SIREAnnotator.init_FAIL(SIREAnnotator.java:175) at com.ibm.nlp.bluemax.SIREAnnotator.initialize(SIREAnnotator.java:289) at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.initializeAnalysisComponent(PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.java:262) at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.initialize(PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.java:169) at org.apache.uima.impl.AnalysisEngineFactory_impl.produceResource(AnalysisEngineFactory_impl.java:94) at org.apache.uima.impl.CompositeResourceFactory_impl.produceResource(CompositeResourceFactory_impl.java:62) at org.apache.uima.UIMAFramework.produceResource(UIMAFramework.java:279) at org.apache.uima.UIMAFramework.produceAnalysisEngine(UIMAFramework.java:407) at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.asb.impl.ASB_impl.setup(ASB_impl.java:256) at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.AggregateAnalysisEngine_impl.initASB(AggregateAnalysisEngine_impl.java:429) at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.AggregateAnalysisEngine_impl.initializeAggregateAnalysisEngine(AggregateAnalysisEngine_impl.java:373) at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.AggregateAnalysisEngine_impl.initialize(AggregateAnalysisEngine_impl.java:186) at org.apache.uima.impl.AnalysisEngineFactory_impl.produceResource(AnalysisEngineFactory_impl.java:94) at org.apache.uima.impl.CompositeResourceFactory_impl.produceResource(CompositeResourceFactory_impl.java:62) at org.apache.uima.UIMAFramework.produceResource(UIMAFramework.java:279) at org.apache.uima.UIMAFramework.produceAnalysisEngine(UIMAFramework.java:407) at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.asb.impl.ASB_impl.setup(ASB_impl.java:256) at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.AggregateAnalysisEngine_impl.initASB(AggregateAnalysisEngine_impl.java:429) at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.AggregateAnalysisEngine_impl.initializeAggregateAnalysisEngine(AggregateAnalysisEngine_impl.java:373) at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.AggregateAnalysisEngine_impl.initialize(AggregateAnalysisEngine_impl.java:186) at org.apache.uima.impl.AnalysisEngineFactory_impl.produceResource(AnalysisEngineFactory_impl.java:94) at org.apache.uima.impl.CompositeResourceFactory_impl.produceResource(CompositeResourceFactory_impl.java:62) at org.apache.uima.UIMAFramework.produceResource(UIMAFramework.java:279) at org.apache.uima.UIMAFramework.produceResource(UIMAFramework.java:331) at org.apache.uima.UIMAFramework.produceAnalysisEngine(UIMAFramework.java:448) at com.ibm.es.nuvo.tokenizer.uima.AbstractCASTokenizer.initUimaTae(AbstractCASTokenizer.java:481) at com.ibm.es.nuvo.tokenizer.uima.AbstractCASTokenizer.configure(AbstractCASTokenizer.java:361) at com.ibm.es.nuvo.tokenizer.uima.CASTokenizer.configure(CASTokenizer.java:208) at com.ibm.es.oze.tokenizer.ExportableCASTokenizer.configure(ExportableCASTokenizer.java:126) at com.ibm.es.oze.tokenizer.OzeCASTokenizer.configure(OzeCASTokenizer.java:92) at com.ibm.es.oze.indexservice.internal.TokenizerFactory$1.configure(TokenizerFactory.java:168) at com.ibm.ilel.tokenizer.service.TokenizerRegistry.create(TokenizerRegistry.java:89) at com.ibm.ilel.tokenizer.service.SingleTokenizerPool.acquire(SingleTokenizerPool.java:242) at com.ibm.ilel.tokenizer.service.AggregateTokenizerPool.acquire(AggregateTokenizerPool.java:107) at com.ibm.ilel.tokenizer.service.AggregateTokenizerPool.acquire(AggregateTokenizerPool.java:65) at com.ibm.ilel.tokenizer.DocumentProcessor.process(DocumentProcessor.java:98) at com.ibm.es.nuvo.tokenizer.XMLDocumentProcessor.tokenizeDocument(XMLDocumentProcessor.java:93) at com.ibm.es.oze.indexservice.internal.dps.embedded.EmbeddedDocumentProcessorDeployer$EmbeddedDocumentProcessor.tokenize(EmbeddedDocumentProcessorDeployer.java:745) at com.ibm.es.oze.indexservice.internal.dps.embedded.EmbeddedDocumentProcessorDeployer$EmbeddedDocumentProcessor.process(EmbeddedDocumentProcessorDeployer.java:666) at com.ibm.es.oze.indexservice.internal.dps.embedded.EmbeddedDocumentProcessorDeployer$EmbeddedDocumentProcessor.process(EmbeddedDocumentProcessorDeployer.java:571) at com.ibm.es.oze.indexservice.internal.dps.socket.SocketDocumentProcessingServer$Worker.processDocument(SocketDocumentProcessingServer.java:784) at com.ibm.es.oze.indexservice.internal.dps.socket.QueuedSocketDocumentProcessingServer$QueueWorker.processDocument(QueuedSocketDocumentProcessingServer.java:106) at com.ibm.es.oze.indexservice.internal.dps.socket.SocketDocumentProcessingServer$Worker.run(SocketDocumentProcessingServer.java:683) Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Bluemax engine initialization failed! ... 43 more '.
Details FFQO0277E An exception was caught with the detail 'com.ibm.ilel.tokenizer.TokenizerException: The tokenizer cannot be initialized with the UIMA descriptor /home/esadmin/esdata/config/machine_learning_annotator_of_atricle.indexservice/specifiers/analytics_document_content.xml and data directory /home/esadmin/esdata/config/machine_learning_annotator_of_atricle.indexservice/resource:/home/esadmin/esdata/config/machine_learning_annotator_of_atricle.indexservice/ner:/opt/IBM/es/configurations/indexservice/data:/home/esadmin/esdata/data.' and a stack trace of 'com.ibm.ilel.tokenizer.TokenizerException: The tokenizer cannot be initialized with the UIMA descriptor /home/esadmin/esdata/config/machine_learning_annotator_of_atricle.indexservice/specifiers/analytics_document_content.xml and data directory /home/esadmin/esdata/config/machine_learning_annotator_of_atricle.indexservice/resource:/home/esadmin/esdata/config/machine_learning_annotator_of_atricle.indexservice/ner:/opt/IBM/es/configurations/indexservice/data:/home/esadmin/esdata/data. at com.ibm.es.nuvo.tokenizer.uima.AbstractCASTokenizer.initUimaTae(AbstractCASTokenizer.java:506) at com.ibm.es.nuvo.tokenizer.uima.AbstractCASTokenizer.configure(AbstractCASTokenizer.java:361) at com.ibm.es.nuvo.tokenizer.uima.CASTokenizer.configure(CASTokenizer.java:208) at com.ibm.es.oze.tokenizer.ExportableCASTokenizer.configure(ExportableCASTokenizer.java:126) at com.ibm.es.oze.tokenizer.OzeCASTokenizer.configure(OzeCASTokenizer.java:92) at com.ibm.es.oze.indexservice.internal.TokenizerFactory$1.configure(TokenizerFactory.java:168) at com.ibm.ilel.tokenizer.service.TokenizerRegistry.create(TokenizerRegistry.java:89) at com.ibm.ilel.tokenizer.service.SingleTokenizerPool.acquire(SingleTokenizerPool.java:242) at com.ibm.ilel.tokenizer.service.AggregateTokenizerPool.acquire(AggregateTokenizerPool.java:107) at com.ibm.ilel.tokenizer.service.AggregateTokenizerPool.acquire(AggregateTokenizerPool.java:65) at com.ibm.ilel.tokenizer.DocumentProcessor.process(DocumentProcessor.java:98) at com.ibm.es.nuvo.tokenizer.XMLDocumentProcessor.tokenizeDocument(XMLDocumentProcessor.java:93) at com.ibm.es.oze.indexservice.internal.dps.embedded.EmbeddedDocumentProcessorDeployer$EmbeddedDocumentProcessor.tokenize(EmbeddedDocumentProcessorDeployer.java:745) at com.ibm.es.oze.indexservice.internal.dps.embedded.EmbeddedDocumentProcessorDeployer$EmbeddedDocumentProcessor.process(EmbeddedDocumentProcessorDeployer.java:666) at com.ibm.es.oze.indexservice.internal.dps.embedded.EmbeddedDocumentProcessorDeployer$EmbeddedDocumentProcessor.process(EmbeddedDocumentProcessorDeployer.java:571) at com.ibm.es.oze.indexservice.internal.dps.socket.SocketDocumentProcessingServer$Worker.processDocument(SocketDocumentProcessingServer.java:784) at com.ibm.es.oze.indexservice.internal.dps.socket.QueuedSocketDocumentProcessingServer$QueueWorker.processDocument(QueuedSocketDocumentProcessingServer.java:106) at com.ibm.es.oze.indexservice.internal.dps.socket.SocketDocumentProcessingServer$Worker.run(SocketDocumentProcessingServer.java:683) Caused by: org.apache.uima.resource.ResourceInitializationException: Initialization of annotator class "com.ibm.nlp.bluemax.SIREAnnotator" failed. (Descriptor: file:/home/esadmin/esdata/config/machine_learning_annotator_of_atricle.indexservice/specifiers/ml/SIREJLW.xml) at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.initializeAnalysisComponent(PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.java:264) at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.initialize(PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.java:169) at org.apache.uima.impl.AnalysisEngineFactory_impl.produceResource(AnalysisEngineFactory_impl.java:94) at org.apache.uima.impl.CompositeResourceFactory_impl.produceResource(CompositeResourceFactory_impl.java:62) at org.apache.uima.UIMAFramework.produceResource(UIMAFramework.java:279) at org.apache.uima.UIMAFramework.produceAnalysisEngine(UIMAFramework.java:407) at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.asb.impl.ASB_impl.setup(ASB_impl.java:256) at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.AggregateAnalysisEngine_impl.initASB(AggregateAnalysisEngine_impl.java:429) at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.AggregateAnalysisEngine_impl.initializeAggregateAnalysisEngine(AggregateAnalysisEngine_impl.java:373) at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.AggregateAnalysisEngine_impl.initialize(AggregateAnalysisEngine_impl.java:186) at org.apache.uima.impl.AnalysisEngineFactory_impl.produceResource(AnalysisEngineFactory_impl.java:94) at org.apache.uima.impl.CompositeResourceFactory_impl.produceResource(CompositeResourceFactory_impl.java:62) at org.apache.uima.UIMAFramework.produceResource(UIMAFramework.java:279) at org.apache.uima.UIMAFramework.produceAnalysisEngine(UIMAFramework.java:407) at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.asb.impl.ASB_impl.setup(ASB_impl.java:256) at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.AggregateAnalysisEngine_impl.initASB(AggregateAnalysisEngine_impl.java:429) at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.AggregateAnalysisEngine_impl.initializeAggregateAnalysisEngine(AggregateAnalysisEngine_impl.java:373) at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.AggregateAnalysisEngine_impl.initialize(AggregateAnalysisEngine_impl.java:186) at org.apache.uima.impl.AnalysisEngineFactory_impl.produceResource(AnalysisEngineFactory_impl.java:94) at org.apache.uima.impl.CompositeResourceFactory_impl.produceResource(CompositeResourceFactory_impl.java:62) at org.apache.uima.UIMAFramework.produceResource(UIMAFramework.java:279) at org.apache.uima.UIMAFramework.produceResource(UIMAFramework.java:331) at org.apache.uima.UIMAFramework.produceAnalysisEngine(UIMAFramework.java:448) at com.ibm.es.nuvo.tokenizer.uima.AbstractCASTokenizer.initUimaTae(AbstractCASTokenizer.java:481) ... 17 more Caused by: org.apache.uima.resource.ResourceInitializationException at com.ibm.nlp.bluemax.SIREAnnotator.initialize(SIREAnnotator.java:320) at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.initializeAnalysisComponent(PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.java:262) ... 40 more Caused by: java.lang.Exception: org.apache.uima.resource.ResourceInitializationException ... 42 more Caused by: org.apache.uima.resource.ResourceInitializationException at com.ibm.nlp.bluemax.SIREAnnotator.init_FAIL(SIREAnnotator.java:175) at com.ibm.nlp.bluemax.SIREAnnotator.initialize(SIREAnnotator.java:289) ... 41 more Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Bluemax engine initialization failed! ... 43 more '. 12*
```

Comment: Thanks I just didn't know where to ask. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem.
I needed to install Fix for 11.0.2.2 and reinstall the SIRE library.
So I problem is gone.

greetings